# Can I know how can I change the Script From Javascript to Typescript Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to change to make it function into my Angular project
**the script code**

```html
<script>
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

btn.onclick = function() {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
    if(btn.classList.contains("bx-menu")) {
        btn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right");
    } else {
        btn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right", "bx-menu");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular does all of these actions differently. Instead of querying DOM elements and affecting them from a script, you **bind** those elements to the scope **this**.

Much of what you need to accomplish actually happens in the HTML, and there is no need for ID tags on your elements

In your app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
   isBXMenu = false; // this isn't required because its just a boolean used in the HTML but it's good form to have it here
   bxMenuAlt = false; // this is now how you switch the class name. When you need it to be bx-menu-alt-right, set this.bxMenuAlt = true

 toggleBXMenu():void() {
    this.bxMenuAlt = !this.bxMenuAlt
  }

}
```

In your HTML

```
 <!-- here is your button -->
 <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn" (click)="isBXMenu=!isBXMenu"
*ngClass="{'bx-menu-alt-right': bxMenuAlt, 'bx-menu': !bxMenuAlt}" ></i>

Toggle sidebar BX Menu</button>

<!-- this is the new sidebar container -->
<div *ngClass="{'bx-menu':isBXMenu}" class='sidebar'>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is the real button for this fuction how can i work in it bcz i already use it in CSS
<i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn" ></i>

Comment: @AnisTaoug - did this help solve your issue? If so, please accept as the answer. THanks